# Instructor can view, edit, delete only theirs courses

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, user-roles

In LearnDash there are courses, lessons, topics and quizzes. I want each instructor to view, edit, delete only their own courses. I managed to do so in the course and topic level but I don’t know how to do so with lessons, quizzes and certificate.
I'm using AAM plugin and User Role Editor plugin.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Unfortunately, your question is kind of off topic with what makes an appropriate question here.  It's something that would be best handled by your plugin developer's support (LearnDash).

Comment: Learndash only give support on plugin level. I was hoping any one with experience in wordpress roles capability can advise me ether using a plugin or adding a code?